# AOP in spring aspect warning

Tags: java, xml, spring, aop

I start learn AOP with spring framework 3.1.2. But I have trouble. In `Beans.xml` context file i wrote:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

    <bean id = "audience" class="com.MySpring.Audience"></bean>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect ref="audience">
            <aop:pointcut id="performance" expression="execution(* com.MySpring.Performer.perform(..))"/>

            <aop:before pointcut-ref="performance" method="seatDown"/>
            <aop:before pointcut-ref="performance" method="turnOffPhone"/>
            <aop:after-returning pointcut-ref="performance" method="applauz"/>
            <aop:after-throwing pointcut-ref="performance" method="demandRefund"/>

        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>

</beans>
```

And Java class

```
public class AOPTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "Beans.xml");

    }

}

// ///
class Audience {

    public void seatDown() {
        out.println("Seat down");
    }

    public void turnOffPhone() {
        out.println("Turn Off Phone");

    }

    public void applauz() {

        out.println("Aplauz");
    }

    public void demandRefund() {
        out.println("We have money back");
    }

}
////
interface Performer{
    void perform();
}
```

But in error console i see:

`Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
Error occured processing XML 'class path resource [org/aopalliance/aop/Advice.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist'. See Error Log for more details    Beans.xml   /AnnotationsWiring/src  line 11 Spring Beans Problem`

And second error:

`Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
Error occured processing XML 'org/springframework/aop/aspectj/AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice'. See Error Log for more details    Beans.xml   /AOP/src    line 12 Spring Beans Problem`

Comment: Do you have the required Jars in your classpath?

Comment: Of course I have all spring jar in classpath.

Comment: This class is not a part of Spring.  You need the aopalliance.jar, http://sourceforge.net/projects/aopalliance/files/

Comment: I download this but I have compile error `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aopalliance.aop.Advice`

Comment: I recommend using Maven or Gradle so that you are not in dependency hell.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are learning spring using examples from spring in action.  In fact, you are missing a `com.springsource.org.apoalliance.jar` file, which is not included in `org.springframework.aop.jar`(though i don't know why).

Please download it at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/aopalliance/files/aopalliance/

You have the `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aopalliance.aop.Advice` because you don't include the jar into your classpath.