# Integrating Spring MVC Apache Tiles and Hibernate

Tags: eclipse, spring, sql-server-2008, hibernate, apache-tiles

I'm trying to integrate Spring MVC + Apache Tiles + Hibernate in Eclipse without Maven or STS environment

M- Hibernate
V- Apache Tiles
C- Spring MVC

1) Integrating Spring MVC + Apache Tiles was successful (using ResourceBundleViewResolver,tiles2.TilesConfigurer)

2) Integrating Spring MVC + Hibernate was successful (using hibernateTransactionManager ,InternalResourceViewResolver, com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)

Now when I try to integrate Spring MVC + Apache Tiles + Hibernate I get an error
Error occurred processing XML 'org/springframework/aop/config/AopNamespaceUtils'

Answer (score 1):

It may be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010970/aop-in-spring-aspect-warning).

Do you have **aopalliance.jar** added to your classpath?

`com.springsource.org.apoalliance.jar file, which is not included in org.springframework.aop.jar`

You can get it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aopalliance/files/aopalliance/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added this reference aopalliance-alpha1.jar and removed the previous file but still I get the error

Comment: If you can show some configurations and files on classpath of integrated application it will be helpful

Comment: I have googled and not able to find any reference for integrating these three technologies. Have you come across any sort of online refercence.

Comment: May be below links could help. Sorry some of them wont open at my office (websense)
http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=spring%20mvc%20%2B%20apache%20tiles%20%2B%20hibernate&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CD0QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffaeddalberto.blogspot.com%2F2011%2F11%2Fspring-mvc-3-with-hibernate-maven-2-and.html&ei=8bt2UbLyGM3FPcCggLAG&usg=AFQjCNH8GS1eSzqap8wzQ5tk2yg-t5oHoA&bvm=bv.45512109,d.ZWU

Comment: another one 
http://www.yves-hoppe.de/java-ee/82-spring-3-mvc-advanced-example?showall=1